# Custom Tab indicator shape in Support Design Widget TabLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

Actually by default tabs are of the rectangle shape but I want to make the custom shape. I have done some coding but now there is some space among the tabs and I want all of them together. Please help!

[What I Have Done](http://www.yogile.com/u89m3zb0/41m/share/?vt=M5ruvzN)

But [what I am trying to do](http://www.yogile.com/jc1fztsr/41m/share/?vt=M5ruvzN) is:

MainActivity.java

```
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("First"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Second"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Third"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/customtabhandler"
    />
```

customtabhandler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/defualttab" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item  android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/onselectedtab" />
```

defualttab.xml

```
<!-- Colored rectangle-->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="95dp"
            android:height="20dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ff30a3b6" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

onselectedtab.xml

```
<!-- Colored rectangle-->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="95dp"
            android:height="20dp" />
        <solid android:color="#89aaaaaa" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- This rectangle for the left side -->
<!-- Its color should be the same as layout's background -->
<item
    android:right="100dp"
    android:left="-100dp"
    android:top="-100dp"
    android:bottom="-100dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff30a3b6" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<!-- This rectangle for the right side -->
<!-- Their color should be the same as layout's background -->
<item
    android:right="-100dp"
    android:left="100dp"
    android:top="-100dp"
    android:bottom="-100dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff30a3b6" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated..

P.S. I have searched a lot on stackoverflow and all I found is for the older library but not for the new one..

Comment: Your links are broken